# KivyMD examples not getting correctly displayed

Tags: material-design, kivy, kivy-language

I've downloaded KivyMD on my windows machine from [here](https://pypi.org/project/kivymd/)

KivyMD path _ _ _\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\kivymd

I'm trying to see how the widgets look with MD and when I run .py files I only get a blank window.

This seems to be the case for almost all examples (.py files) under the kivymd folder.

Appreciate any inputs.

[image: a blank window].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. cd ...\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\demos\kitchen_sink
2. run `python main.py`

## Note

Not all *.py* programs in *...\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\kivymd* will display a window. You can run `python accordion.py` and it will display a window of accordion widget.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs ikolim. On running main.py I get the following error.

\Lib\site-packages\KivyMD-master\demos\kitchen_sink\main.py", line 8, in <module>
from kivymd.bottomsheet import MDListBottomSheet, MDGridBottomSheet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd.bottomsheet'

*bottomsheet is located in a different location* ----> \Lib\site-packages\KivyMD-master\kivymd

Comment: Download the latest [KivyMD](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD) from GitLab and install it.